# How to a specify a property that is a function in Json Schema

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, specifications

I want to be able to define functions with parameters and return type for my JavaScript object specification. I am hoping to be able to do this using JSONSchema. But, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A JavaScript object that gets a product from Acme's catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "getProduct": {
      "description": "returns a product object when a product id is provided as a parameter",
      "type": "function",
      "parameters": ["id": uuid],
      "returnType": object
    }
  },
}
```

Does anybody know of a project or tool that will allow me to do this? Triple thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you store a function in a json object? How would you serialize and deserialize it? Json does not provide support for functions

Comment: I am looking to specify the object, not define it, very much as one can specify an API in OpenApi and then use the specification to implement the particular API.

Comment: also asked on https://github.com/json-schema-org/community/discussions/65#discussioncomment-1443171

Answer (score 2):

JSON Schema does not have any capacity to describe functions, due to the fact that JSON cannot express functions. JSON Schema is defined over the data model expressible in JSON.

current versions of the JSON Schema specification are quite extensible with the addition of vocabularies. although it would not be consistently interoperable, a vocabulary to describe functions might be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can always define functions as properties of JSON objects by key value syntax. like this:

```js
    const Product = {
      id: 50,
      getProduct: function(id){
        return 'product '+id;
      }
    }
```

But if you want to serialize this JSON to exchange it in some way. you have to override JSON.stringfy replacer function like this

```
    JSON.stringify(Product, function(key, value){
      if(typeof value === 'function')
        return value.toString();
      else return value;
    });
```

And if you like to add comments to your JSON, you can add some key/value like  _comment:"Type your comment here" to your object.

Comment: I am looking to specify the object rather than define it. Still thanks for the suggestion.